# Lots of Errors Trying to Create Invoice

Tags: tables, errors

I will preface this by saying I do know there is an invoice package. It wasn't working with my setup and I wished to have a little more customization. So, in order to replicate that package I created a new environment and a new command within that environment. Unfortunately it does not seem to work and I cannot figure out why.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{invoice}{%
  \newcounter{total}%
  \newcommand*{\additem}[2]{\addtocounter{total}{##2}##1&&##2}%
  \tabularx{\linewidth}{Xc@{}r}
    \toprule
    \textbf{DESCRIPTION} && \textbf{AMOUNT}\\
    \midrule}{%
    \bottomrule
    \newcounter{wholetotal}\setcounter{wholetotal}{\value{total}/100}
    \newcounter{fractotal}\setcounter{fractotal}{\value{total}-\value{wholetotal}*100}
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{TOTAL:}} & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \$ & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \arabic{wholetotal}.\ifnum\value{fractotal}<10 0\fi\arabic{fractotal} \\
  \endtabularx
  Please pay the amount in full by check made out to ``Company''}

\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}
  \additem{Data collection}{1500}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

And I'm getting a ton of errors but here is a sample:

```
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \noalign.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \endgroup inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing { inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing { inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing } inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
test.tex|25 error| Missing \cr inserted.
test.tex|25 error| Misplaced \cr.
```

Comment: `\additem` is set to take only two arguments, yet you provide three in your example. Strange, as it only adds the `00` at the end of the item listed.

Comment: @Werner Haha sorry I was working on getting `\additem` to have arguments for whole dollars and cents, but I figured I'd get rid of those errors when asking this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `invoice` package already, but here ... we don't use it ;-)

Don't say `\newcounter{...}` in an environment that is assumed to be called more than once.

The main errors are missing `\tabularnewline` (or `\\`) statements and the alignment errors that can be prevented with `\noalign{...}`, because `\multicolumn` expects to be in the first item in a cell (as Werner stated below ;-))

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{total}
\newcounter{wholetotal}
\newcounter{fractotal}

\newenvironment{invoice}{%
  \setcounter{total}{0}
  \setcounter{wholetotal}{0}
  \setcounter{fractotal}{0}
  \newcommand*{\additem}[2]{\addtocounter{total}{##2} ##1&&##2 \tabularnewline}%
  \tabularx{\linewidth}{Xc@{}r}
  \toprule
  \textbf{DESCRIPTION} && \textbf{AMOUNT}\\
  \midrule
}{%
  \bottomrule
  \tabularnewline
  \noalign{\setcounter{wholetotal}{\value{total}/100}}
  \noalign{\setcounter{fractotal}{\value{total}-\value{wholetotal}*100}}
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{TOTAL:}} & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \textdollar & \cellcolor{blue!10!white} \arabic{wholetotal}.\ifnum\value{fractotal}<10 0\fi\arabic{fractotal} \\
  \tabularnewline% More space at the end
  \endtabularx

  Please pay the amount in full by check made out to ``Company''}

\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}
  \additem{Data collection}{1500}%{00}
  \additem{LaTeX book}{50000}%{00}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\noalign` because `\multicolumn` expects to be the first item within a cell.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, changed and added your comment (with reference)