# Customized Class with table of dynamic data

Tags: tables, document-classes

I am trying to write a class that could produce a table with employee name and salary in it. I need the user of the class is to be able to just write the employee name and the salary inside the tex file. Minimal example is the following:

```
\ProvidesClass{Employee}[2016/07/11 version 1.00 Employee's Salaries]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass{article}
 %%%
 \RequirePackage{tabu,url}

  \newenvironment{salary}{
    \begin{center}


         \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
               \hline 
                Name  & Salary \\ \hline

                John & 40,000\$\\ \hline
                %%% Here I do not want a pre--defined data

          \end{tabular}

   \end{center}


}{%}
```

}

and my tex file looks like this

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,fullpage]{SXClass}
\begin{document}

  \begin{salary}
   %%%% I would like to add the names here as the following:
   %%%% \employee{empName}{empSalary}
   %%%% \employee{Joseph}{40,000}
   %%%% \employee{Bob}{70,000}
   %%%% and they will appear directly into the table.
   \end{salary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not about salaries, but related (somehow): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318961/lots-of-errors-trying-to-create-invoice/318963#318963

Comment: There's a mismatch between the class named `Employee` and the class used in the document (`SXClass`), however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `longtable` which is both already centered by default and capable of page breaks.

```
\ProvidesClass{Employee}[2016/07/11 version 1.00 Employee's Salaries]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass{article}
%%% 
\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{url} % Why?


\newcommand{\employee}[2]{%
  #1 & #2\tabularnewline
  \hline
}

\newenvironment{salary}{%
  \begin{longtable}{|p{6cm}|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Salary} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \endhead
    }{%
    \end{longtable}
  }
\endinput
```

Here's the driver

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,fullpage]{Employee}

\begin{document}

\begin{salary}
  \employee{Wonder Woman}{500,000}
  \employee{Joseph}{40,000}
  \employee{Bob}{70,000}
  \employee{John}{10,000}
  \employee{Paul}{210,000}
\end{salary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** A version with `siunitx` column formatting:

```
\ProvidesClass{Employee}[2016/07/11 version 1.00 Employee's Salaries]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass{article}
%%% 
%\RequirePackage{tabu}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{url} % Why?


\newcommand{\employee}[2]{%
  #1 & #2\tabularnewline
  \hline
}

\newenvironment{salary}{%
  \begin{longtable}{|p{6cm}|S[table-alignment=right]|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Salary}} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \endhead
    }{%
    \end{longtable}
  }
\endinput
```

And the modified driver:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,fullpage]{Employee}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{copy-decimal-marker=true}

\begin{salary}
  \employee{Wonder Woman}{500,000}
  \employee{Joseph}{40,000}
  \employee{Bob}{70,000}
  \employee{John}{10,000}
  \employee{Paul}{210,000}
\end{salary}

\end{document}
```